# Vue.js change property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, button, disabled-input

```
<ul class="col-12">
   <div v-for="(todo, n) in todos">
     <i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down mr-1 ml-2"></i>
      **<li class="mt-2 todo" @click="myFilter(n)"** :class="todo.isActive ? 'active' : '' ">
         <!-- {{ todo.name }} -->
        </li>
        <li class="button-container bg-light"> 
        **<button** class="ml-1 btn btn-primary rounded-circle btn-sm" @click="toggleHidden(n)" v- 
        if="todo.isHidden == true" **:disabled='false'**><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
          </button>
        </li>
   </div>
</ul>
```

I have this code and I want that, when you click on li with "myFilter (n)", in the button :disabled it changes from "false" to "true"

Comment: Just add a new property inside `todos` array like `isDisabled` and just toggle it based on the click. You are already using similar logic for `toggleHidden` with `isHidden` property.

Comment: ok, but I want that at the click of li must change the disabled which is inside the button not of the todo

Comment: but the button is for the todo only, right?

Comment: yes, I did as you said, : class = "todo.isDisabled? 'disabled': ''"
it works, I only change the css properties of the button, but the button continues to work. I want it not to work

Comment: You need to update the `disabled` property of the button also along with the class. Like `:disabled="!!todo.isDisabled"`

Comment: ooooooh perfect! now works! thank you very mutch!